# Would this question be acceptable: Were the 7 days of creation 7 Earth days?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/783/the-7-days-of-creation-did-god-create-the-world-in-6-earth-days) on bible hermeneutics and it got closed (for the reasons commented). It was suggested that this question might be better suitable on this website. But I want to see what the general response *would* be from this community from such a question before I actually ask it. This is an effort to see the evidence or different backed up opinions of both sides of the equation, and given that, see what the general accepted belief is amongst Christians. Also to provide more insight to everyone on both beliefs.

Comment: My +1 is for thinking about the kind of question and making the effort to ask on meta first, not to say "yes this would be an acceptable question" :)

Comment: This question has basically [already been asked](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/642/20).

Comment: @Flimzy Ah, Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Mason has noted](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/819/30), that kind of question is generally *Not Constructive*. Christianity is already split on both sides of that fence and rather than arriving at an answer to your question you'll start a mini war in the answer section and a discussion thread a mile long in comments.

In a case like this you have a couple of options.

1. As for an overview of which Christian doctrines address the issue. This would sort of scope out the territory so you had some idea what the positions on the issue are.
2. Pick a viewpoint your interested in an ask how that view is defended or who holds it or its history or something along those lines.
3. Pick a specific point of the argument and ask for a comparison between the two. (Usually this would have to be much more specific than the whole issue you are suggesting asking about)

Lastly be aware of a couple more points:

- This has been asked before. A lot of questions have been forwarded on the topic already. Many have been *Not Constructive* but a few on each side, includeing ones dealing with the basis for each issue, are available for looking at. Make sure you aren't asking a duplicate question.
- This is a non-salvitic issue. Although people do get really hot about it because the implications of having different interpretive methods are quite serious, the actual right/wrong of this issue is recognized by most Christians to be one that does't affect salvation either way.
- No question you ask on this site can be expected to reconcile differences between different traditions and doctrinal frameworks in Christianity. **You can ask about them** and they can be examined and explained in detail **but don't try to pit them against each other**. However you end up asking **it must be asked in a way that answers could be verified as true even by somebody who doesn't agree with the viewpoint**. For example if you ask about Catholicism I as a Protestant should be able to verify that the answers being given do indeed represent Catholicism even if I disagree with their beliefs. A right answer should involve an accurate representation of the doctrines held by identifiable Christians. A right answer is not going to be one that "once and for all" settles a disagreement between.

**This is not a discussion board and the purpose is not to provide a venue for debate. It is to provide canonical answers to answerable questions.** The questions that fit this format will be ones that can be verified as being true without having to believe exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though I'm not trying to pit anyone against each other. I was just trying to see the different standpoints people hold and why. And saying leave the emotions and beliefs out of it, and see what people are trying to say about why they think one over the other. I'm not 100% sure myself, though I have my own assumptions, and I'm open to the subject. IMHO I think its lame people would get so heated on such a topic that when it comes to salvation has no importance, and on verses that are so vague could leave anyone Christian on either edge of the sword.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with some better options on how to approach the subject! I will use them.

Comment: I edited my question in the op link. That's not going off your suggestions tho, I will do that later on a new post :)

Answer (score 0):

The response here would be for a moderator to ask you to specify a doctrinal framework, because there are many different opinions on this subject and different branches of Christianity will have widely different responses to the question.

Comment: I'm not looking for answers from a given doctrine. I'm looking for answers from God's people in general as a whole, bible scholars and enthusiasts, Christ followers, theologians, etc.

Comment: I'm open to different opinions and responses. Please read the entire question I linked to. Thanks!

Comment: I understand exactly where you're coming from.  Unfortunately, the moderators here have reached a consensus that that kind of open-ended question tends to devolve into a popularity contest (everyone votes for the viewpoint that they agree with) and doesn't end up accomplishing anything, so they're frowned upon nowadays.

Comment: Isn't that one of the reasons people vote anyway? Not necessarily in their belief alone, but in the answer's efforts to back it up (if needed), and how it resonates with the reader?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to make this into two questions: "What supports young earth creation?" and "what supports old earth creation?". Although that would kind of defeat the purpose of my question, to come to some kind of community consensus towards one over the other.

Comment: @Shredder: See [my full answer](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/820/30) but this is a QnA site, not a debate forum. This format is not for developing consensus on issues that don't have it already, it is for documenting the current state of affairs. It might serve to raise awareness for those that follow both sides of issues, but it will is not well suited to the purpose you describe. We simply cannot, even by majority consensus, promote one competing set of doctrines over another.